how to resize image (background) only for width (height is static)?
I have to get the result: the background image should shrink to fill the entire screen without changing height; so depends on the device width: image width = device width and image height is always 746px.
expected result:

Current result:



body {
    color: var(--color-black);
    background-image: url("./images/backgrounds/main.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100vw 740px;
    background-position: top left;
}
<svg
    width="1439"
    height="740"
    viewBox="0 0 1439 740"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
    <path
        d="M98.4726 637.816C58.958 651.755 25.837 669.251 0 688.25V0H1439V636.812C1355.3 584.281 1275.96 582.088 1207.85 596.928C1104.81 619.379 1007.79 667.609 908.468 703.067C882.986 712.164 855.933 721.065 828.042 728.383C586.346 791.797 334.116 554.688 98.4726 637.816Z"
        fill="url(#paint0_linear_111_752)"
    />
    <defs>
        <linearGradient
            id="paint0_linear_111_752"
            x1="37.9551"
            y1="338.623"
            x2="1439"
            y2="338.623"
            gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
            <stop stop-color="#390696" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#8C129A" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>




We can't change the size of an embedded SVG image using css background properties. I assume this isn't what you're trying to do?

THANKS, recopied image as .png and problem has left. ^_^

in my opinion if you add the background-attachment property in the body and set it's value to fixed so the image will be good for all the devices so try to add this property like that:
body {
 color: var(--color-black);
 background-image: url("./images/backgrounds/main.svg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100vw 740px;
 background-position: top left;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

also you can change the position to center if it doesn't work good this is (optional) only.

Why does background-attachment help here?

because i had the same problem a lot and when i learnt this property i fixed this problem because it makes the image fixed in the website so it works good in all devices

@user26362092, hello, thanks. I dont need to have a fixed image background. I already tried this solution, but its not that i need
